# Mac OS X is not detecting USB Wi-Fi adaptor

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, modem

I need some help regarding hardware configuration. The [built-in Wi-Fi module?] of my Mac stopped working so I bought a USB Wi-Fi adapter, but I am not able to figure out how to configure it on Snow Leopard. It's a Chinese brand, namely "TP-LINK TL-WN727N, 150 Mbps". The same hardware works well in Windows via Boot Camp. Please tell me if I am missing something, and how I can configure it on my Mac.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X does not have any built-in drivers for USB Wi-Fi adaptors. I would normally say that you need to download and install the Mac OS X drivers from your hardware vendor, but it looks like that vendor doesn't provide Mac OS X drivers for that card. Also note that third-party Wi-Fi adaptors like this usually can't fake like they're a real AirPort card, so they can't be controlled via the usual AirPort menu extra. The vendor has to provide their own Mac GUI software for letting you scan for networks, select networks, etc.

I think your best bet is to get your AirPort card fixed, or look somewhere like [OWC](http://macsales.com/) for replacement internal wireless modules that fit your model of Mac.